# Python shutil.make_archive resulting in larger file than original

Tags: python

I want to tar a 49 GB folder so it's compressed, but not persisted afterwards.

I'm using the below code to create a temporary directory (I chose the parent path) and then `shutil.make_archive`:

```
import tempfile
import shutil

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=temp_dir_path) as temp_output_dir:
    output_path = shutil.make_archive(temp_output_dir, "tar", dir_to_tar)
```

However, the size of the tar file generated is larger than when I `du -sh` the original folder. I stopped the code when it reached 51 GB.

Am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tar (*t*ape *ar*chive) format doesn't compress, it just "archives" files together (it's basically just a directory structure and the files it contains shoved into a single file). Definitionally, it's a little *larger* than the original data.

If you want the tarball to be compressed so it ends up smaller than the original data, use one of the compressed `format` arguments [to `make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive), e.g. `'gztar'` (faster, worse compression, most portable) or `'xztar'` (slower, best compression, somewhat less portable) instead of just `'tar'`.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that shortly after posting. However, you noticed it! When you mention xztar portability, is it okay on Linux?

Comment: @user997112: Basically every Linux distro has it as, at the very least, an optional package to install. It's just not default installed in *quite* as many places as `gzip` (it's pretty darn common nowadays though).